# Slice circular linestring by shortest distance between 2 points

Tags: polygon, linestring, mapbox-gl-js, turf

I have a polygon of a farming field. I am dropping 2 Points along the field borders in order to easily measure the distance between those points.

This works great most of the time, but in some situations the sliced line takes "the long way round".

### Question

**How do I slice a linestring in the direction of the shortest distance between the 2 points?**

#### More context

1. First I take a polygon and convert it to a linestring
2. Then I use Turf functions to slice the line at the start and end points

```
import { polygonToLine } from '@turf/polygon-to-line'
import lineSlice from '@turf/line-slice'

const slicedLineString = lineSlice(
    startPoint,
    endPoint,
    polygonToLine(polygonFeature)
)
```

Blank context image of the field:

[image: starting point]

The below image is correct, the shortest distance shown by the black line:

[image: working correctly]

The below image shows the black line measuring in the wrong direction, not the shortest distance/direction between the 2 points.

[image: not working correctky]

Answer (score 3):

Explanation for this is simple. If the start/end point of line string created with the `polygonToLine` method is between measuring points on the short section that you want to measure, measuring has to occur the long way around, since there is no path between measuring point the short way.

Measuring the shortest path is also simple. Get total line string length `L`, get sliced line string length `M1` and calculate difference `M2 = L - M1`. Desired measurement is then the smaller of `M1` and `M2`.

But painting/drawing the obtained shortest path would require some coding.

Comment: That makes sense. I wonder if I could get all the coordinates of the linestring and compare each against my 2 "cut" points and find the one that is furthest from both. Then re-arrange the order of the coordinates so that that coordinate is the start. This gives me the best chance of the break not being between my 2 points.

Comment: The above answer is answer to your question about getting correct distance and the reason why you sometimes get it wrong. As I wrote, to draw line between points would require some coding, and that is separate question.

Comment: I've solved this in an answer above, your first sentance lead me to the solution so thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by:

1. Looping through all the coordinates of the linestring, finding the coordinate pair that is furthest from both the start and coordinates
2. Re-order the linestring coordinates so that it starts from this furthest away point

```
const lineString = polygonToLine(JSON.parse(this.parcel.geometry))

// Loop through all coordinates of linestring Feature, find coordinate pair that is furthest from both the start and end coordinates
let furthestDistance = 0
let furthestIndex = 0

for (let i = 0; i < lineString.geometry.coordinates.length; i++) {
    const distanceToStart = distance(lineString.geometry.coordinates[i], this.startCoordinates, {
        units: 'kilometers'
    })

    const distanceToEnd = distance(lineString.geometry.coordinates[i], this.endCoordinates, {
        units: 'kilometers'
    })

    const totalDistance = distanceToStart + distanceToEnd

    if (totalDistance > furthestDistance) {
        furthestDistance = totalDistance
        furthestIndex = i
    }
}

// Re-order linestring geometry coordinates so that the furthest coordinate pair is at the start
const reorderedCoordinates = lineString.geometry.coordinates
    .slice(furthestIndex)
    .concat(lineString.geometry.coordinates.slice(0, furthestIndex))

lineString.geometry.coordinates = reorderedCoordinates

this.slicedLine = lineSlice(this.startCoordinates, this.endCoordinates, lineString)
```